# Execute shortcut or menu action in particular application window

Tags: macos, xcode5, sudo

Is there a script option to actualy go through all XCode opened projects (application windows) and execute menu action Product->Stop or executing shortcut "CMD + ."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run Apple Script in **Xcode** at the beginning of each run You can create shell script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

osascript -e 'tell application "Xcode"                                                                                                                                                                                                        
activate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
set activeWindow to window 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
set windowName to name of activeWindow                                                                                                                                                                                                        
repeat with aWindow in windows                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "`" using command down                                                                                                                                                                          
    if name of aWindow is not equal to windowName then                                                                                                                                                                                            
        if name of aWindow is not equal to "" then                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "." using command down                                                                                                                                                                          
        end if                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    end if                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
end repeat                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
end tell'
```

Then in  **Xcode** go to Preferences->Behaviours->Starts->Run and choose Your script.

Comment: does it need anything else to be written? e.g. #!/bin/bash or exit 0 ?

Comment: You can make an app and place it in the **Dock** if You like. Open **Apple Script editor**, paste this script and save it as application. Than double clicking this app will run this. If You want to run it in Terminal You have to call `osascript` to execute Apple Script.

Comment: I need to run it from XCode as script - there is an option to choose script from behaviours->Running->Starts preference. I'm new to mac and dont know (yet) anything on how to create this script.

Comment: shortcut is executed as I can see in apple script editor, but only the front project window is affected, is there a way to bring it to front before executing shortcut? Also is there a shell script similar to this as I cant select apple script

Comment: :) my quick fix is to use another shortcut:
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "`" using command down

Comment: Sorry for another noob Q, how to create the shell script?

Comment: make a txt document with that script (For example on Desktop and name it stopXcode.sh).  In Terminal do:  
`cd ~/Desktop`  
`chmod +x stopXcode.sh`

Comment: It works:) but not yet solves the problem:) As this also stops current project from running - is there a way to: remember current window and skip it, then set focus back to the current project window? btw. I'm not accepting it yet as I want to give you bounty:)